# Using CodeModuleListener + Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am trying to use CodeModuleListener in my application.  I am testing this on simulator. After I run my application I add another cod file to the simulator but the moduleAdded(..) method of CodeModuleListener is not called, when I expect it would be.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application_Load theApp = new Application_Load();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();

           try 
              {
                   CodeModuleManager.addListener(UiApplication.getApplication(), cmListener);
              } 
              catch (NullPointerException e) 
              {
                   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                   e.printStackTrace();
              } 
}


public Application_Load()
    {
     cmListener = new CodeModuleListener() 
           {

                public void modulesDeleted(String[] moduleNames) 
                {
                    String s = "APP DELETED ====================>";
                    System.out.println(s);          
                    //writeFile(s, "file:///SDCard/uploadedfile.txt");
                    deleteFile("file:///system/databases/TestApp/TestDB.db");
                }

                public void modulesAdded(int[] handles) 
                {
                    String s = "APP ADDED ====================>";
                    System.out.println(s);          
                    //writeFile(s, "file:///SDCard/uploadedfile.txt");
                    deleteFile("file:///system/databases/TestApp/TestDB.db");
                }

                public void moduleDeletionsPending(String[] moduleNames) 
                {
                    String s = "APP IS DELETING ====================>";
                    System.out.println(s);          
                    //writeFile(s, "file:///SDCard/uploadedfile.txt");
                    deleteFile("file:///system/databases/TestApp/TestDB.db");
                }
           };

        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                 UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new TestScreen());              
             }
         });
    }
```

Comment: Is the cod file that you're adding showing up or is there some problem installing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listener before the `theApp.enterEventDispatcher();` call.